# import Recharts.js library to jsx react file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am looking to use [Recharts](http://recharts.org/) as a graph system for my React app.

To install I have gone to the installation guide and entered the following command in the terminal

`$ npm install recharts`

My jsx file then looks like the code below: 
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import ReCharts from "recharts";

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var data = [{ name: 'a', value: 12 }];
    return (
     <LineChart width={400} height={400} data={data}>
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#8884d8" />
    </LineChart>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

It is not working as I am not importing recharges correctly. Can anyone advise and explain how this should be imported and any advice on how I soul know if I am exporting another library without any explicit guidance in its documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need import `LineChart` and `Line` components from `Recharts`, because this library does not have default exports [**`Recharts index`**](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/src/index.js)

```
import { LineChart, Line } from 'recharts';
```

**Update**

also you need change `dataKey`, from `'uv'` to `'value'` because in `data` you use `value` as key for chart values

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/xyw5e9yb/34/)